# Syntax for form data elements using stimulus-library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, trix

Reference document [stimulus-library](https://github.com/Sub-Xaero/stimulus-library/) and its [relevant example](https://github.com/Sub-Xaero/stimulus-library/blob/master/examples/controllers/trix_modifier_controller.html)

Attempting to get the rich text area - also using mobility - wher the goal is to alter the trix-editor tag as follows:

```
<trix-editor
  data-controller="trix-modifier"
  data-no-file-uploads
></trix-editor>
```

the following fail

```
<%= form.rich_text_area "translatable_content_#{Mobility.normalize_locale(user_idioma.idioma.code.to_s)}", rows: 20,  
data: { controller: 'trix-modifier'}, data: { 'no-file-uploads' } %>

<%= form.rich_text_area "translatable_content_#{Mobility.normalize_locale(user_idioma.idioma.code.to_s)}", rows: 20,  
data: { controller: 'trix-modifier', 'no-file-uploads' } %>
```

while a simple controller element definition renders correctly:

```
<%= form.rich_text_area "translatable_content_#{Mobility.normalize_locale(user_idioma.idioma.code.to_s)}", rows: 20,  
data: { controller: 'trix-modifier'} %>
```

how should the syntax be set to generate the proper tag impeding file uploads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as a simple reference, figured out by poking around:

```
<%= form.rich_text_area "translatable_content_#{Mobility.normalize_locale(user_idioma.idioma.code.to_s)}", rows: 20,  
data: { controller: 'trix-modifier', 'no-file-uploads' => true } %>
```